# How can I move XML elements with PHP's SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can I move an xml element elsewhere in a document? So I have this:

```
<outer>
    <foo>
        <child name="a"/>
        <child name="b"/>
        <child name="c"/>
    </foo>
    <bar />
</outer>
```

and want to end up with:

```
<outer>
    <foo />
    <bar>
        <child name="a"/>
        <child name="b"/>
        <child name="c"/>
    </bar>
</outer>
```

Using PHP's simpleXML.

Is there a function I'm missing (appendChild-like)?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.addChild.php

Comment: I don't want to create a new child. I want to move an existing one.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I want to clone attributes and child nodes, not just create a new empty node.

Comment: Use the [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead, which has methods like `appendChild`. With those classes, it is a relatively simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a recusrive function that clones the attributes and children. There is no other way to `move` the children with SimpleXML

Answer (score -1):

```
class ExSimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement {
    //ajoute un object à un autre
    function sxml_append(ExSimpleXMLElement $to, ExSimpleXMLElement $from) {
        $toDom = dom_import_simplexml($to);
        $fromDom = dom_import_simplexml($from);
        $toDom->appendChild($toDom->ownerDocument->importNode($fromDom, true));
    }
}


    $customerXML = <<<XML
    <customer>
        <address_billing>
            <address_book_id>10</address_book_id>
            <customers_id>20</customers_id>
            <telephone>0120524152</telephone>
            <entry_country_id>73</entry_country_id>
        </address_billing>
        <countries>
            <countries_id>73</countries_id>
            <countries_name>France</countries_name>
            <countries_iso_code_2>FR</countries_iso_code_2>
        </countries>
    </customer>
    XML;

$customer = simplexml_load_string($customerXML, "ExSimpleXMLElement");
$customer->sxml_append($customer->address_billing, $customer->countries);

echo $customer->asXML();


    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <customer>
        <address_billing>
            <address_book_id>10</address_book_id>
            <customers_id>20</customers_id>
            <telephone>0120524152</telephone>
            <entry_country_id>73</entry_country_id>
            <countries>
               <countries_id>73</countries_id>
               <countries_name>France</countries_name>
               <countries_iso_code_2>FR</countries_iso_code_2>
            </countries>
        </address_billing>
    </customer>
```